# php monthly attendance table

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a monthly attendance system which displays how many hours an employee has worked each day of the month.The table looks like this-[image: monthly attendance sample pic]

The php code -

```
    $s = $_GET['s'];
$y = date('Y');

$fdt = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($y.'-'.$s.'-'.'01'));
$ldt = date('Y-m-t',strtotime($y.'-'.$s.'-'.'01'));
$nd = date('t',strtotime($y.'-'.$s.'-'.'01'));
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT emp_id_fk, Resource_Name , ROUND(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(COALESCE(`end_time`,NOW()),`start_time`)))/3600,1) as Hrs, CAST(`start_time` AS DATE) as cd FROM `attendance` LEFT JOIN resource ON attendance.`emp_id_fk` = resource.`Resource_ID` WHERE CAST(`start_time` AS DATE) BETWEEN :s AND :e GROUP BY emp_id_fk, Resource_Name, CAST(`start_time` AS DATE)");

$stmt->bindParam(':s', $fdt);
$stmt->bindParam(':e', $ldt);

$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($data);
$ret = "";
$id = array_column($data,'emp_id_fk');
$name = array_column($data,'Resource_Name');
$id = array_unique($id);
$name = array_unique($name);

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($id); $i++){
    $ret.='<tr>
            <td>'.$name[$i].'</td>';

        for($j=0; $j<sizeof($nd); $j++){
            $cd = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($y.'-'.$s.'-'.($j+1)));
            $d = date('l',strtotime($y.'-'.$s.'-'.($j+1)));

            if($d != 'Sunday' && $d != 'Saturday'){

                for($k=0; $k<sizeof($data); $k++){

                    if( $id[$i] == $data[$k]['emp_id_fk']){

                        if($cd == $data[$k]['cd']){
                            $ret.='<td>'.($data[$k]['Hrs']).'</td>';
                        }else{
                            $ret.='<td>0</td>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    $ret.='</tr>';
}

echo $ret;
```

As seen in the image, the second forloop($j loop) is iterating only once where as it should iterate 28,30 or 31 times based on the month. What my expected output is that for each employee there should be a value for everyday of the week and if there is no record for a particular date it should display 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what i can see, $j<sizeof($nd) is the likely culprit, in that sizeof expects an array, but $nd is just a date that you set on line 5. I'm surprised it's even running twice.

Comment: I hope you're running a 64-bit version of PHP. If not, you should really look into the DateTime object: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php. Year 2038 problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP function sizeof() is an alias for count().
The function count() is to count all elements in an array, or something in an object.

Change:

```
for($j=0; $j<sizeof($nd); $j++){
```

To:

```
for($j=1; $j<=$nd; $j++) {
```

Comment: You're welcome! I get stumped by things like this too if I've been in the code too much that day. Sometimes it is just good to have another set of eyes. :-)